# Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Tags: php, date, postback, autopostback, postbackurl

An error:

> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long

This is a postback php scripts part,

```
$conv_time = time();
$click_time_to_date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $mysql['click_time']));
$conv_time_to_date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $conv_time));
$diff = $click_time_to_date->diff($conv_time_to_date);
$mysql['time_difference'] =  $db->real_escape_string($diff->d.' days, '.$diff->h.' hours, '.$diff->i.' min and '.$diff->s.' sec');
$mysql['conv_time'] = $db->real_escape_string($conv_time);
$mysql['ip'] = $db->real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
$mysql['user_agent'] = $db->real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Comment: The datatype of one of your uses in the date() function is not of the type long. A "long" data type is a number, without any other characters, for example a unix timestamp is a long datatype. What is the value of $mysql['click_time'] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `click_time` field probably is of type `DATETIME`, and `date()` expects the second parameter to be a timestamp (`long`).

Try replacing line #2 with:

```
$click_time_to_date = new DateTime($mysql['click_time']);
```

Or make sure that your `click_time` field is of type `TIMESTAMP`.